# Why my log will be redirected into catalina.out?

Tags: java, tomcat7, log4j2, catalina.out

In my application, I use log4j2 to output log.

```
<!-- log4j2 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-beta9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-beta9</version>
</dependency>
```

And the app hosts in Tomcat7.

Firstly I use the default way to output Catalina.out, but I found my app log will be redirected into Catalina.out. So I follow the Tomcat's documents.
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html

Then change it with log4j's way. But finally, it runs as default.

```
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, CATALINA

# Define all the appenders
log4j.appender.CATALINA = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.CATALINA.File = ${catalina.base}/logs/catalina
log4j.appender.CATALINA.Append = true
log4j.appender.CATALINA.Encoding = UTF-8
# Roll-over the log once per day
log4j.appender.CATALINA.DatePattern = '.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
log4j.appender.CATALINA.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CATALINA.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n

log4j.appender.LOCALHOST = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.File = ${catalina.base}/logs/localhost
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.Append = true
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.Encoding = UTF-8
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.DatePattern = '.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n

log4j.appender.MANAGER = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.MANAGER.File = ${catalina.base}/logs/manager
```

Any one meet such kind of problem, can show me the solution to avoid this?

PS:
The logger module design as:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.util.Date;

public class Logger {

    private static org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger logger = org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(Logger.class
            .getName());

    public static void error(String proj, String opera, String param, String msg) {
        logger.error(log("Error", proj, opera, param, msg));
    }

    public static void debug(String proj, String opera, String param, String msg) {
        logger.debug(log("Debug", proj, opera, param, msg));
    }

    public static void warn(String proj, String opera, String param, String msg) {
        logger.warn(log("Warn", proj, opera, param, msg));
    }

    public static void info(String proj, String opera, String param, String msg) {
        logger.info(log("Info", proj, opera, param, msg));
    }

    private static String log(String type, String proj, String opera, String param, String msg) {
        // Build log content with JSON
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("{\"time\": \"");
        sb.append(DateUtil.formatMilliSecond(new Date()));
        sb.append("\", \"level\": ");
        sb.append("\"" + type + "\", \"module\": ");
        sb.append("\"" + proj + "\", \"operation\": ");
        sb.append("\"" + opera + "\"");

        if (!StringUtil.isEmpty(param)) {
            sb.append(", \"parameter\": \"" + param + "\"");
        }

        if (!StringUtil.isEmpty(msg)) {
            sb.append(", \"message\": \"" + msg + "\"");
        }
        sb.append("}");
        writeLog(sb.toString());
        return sb.toString();
    }


    public static void setLog(String module) {
        logger = org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(module);
    }

}
```

And the log4j2 configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration status="OFF">
    <appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%msg%n"/>
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="MinerLog" fileName="/local/logs/miners.log"
                     filePattern="/local/logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/miners-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%msg%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="20 MB"/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
        <RollingFile name="CaptainLog" fileName="/local/logs/captain.log"
                     filePattern="/local/logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/captain-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%msg%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="20 MB"/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
        <RollingFile name="DataProviderLog" fileName="/local/logs/das_dataprovider.log"
                     filePattern="/local/logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/dataprovider-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%msg%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="20 MB"/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    </appenders>
    <loggers>
        <root level="debug">
            <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
        </root>
        <logger name="miner" level="debug">
            <appender-ref ref="MinerLog" level="info"/>
            <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
        </logger>
        <logger name="captain" level="debug">
            <appender-ref ref="CaptainLog" level="info"/>
            <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
        </logger>
        <logger name="dataprovider" level="debug">
            <appender-ref ref="DataProviderLog" level="info"/>
            <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
        </logger>
    </loggers>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Change the value of this  tag to local file **log4j.appender.CATALINA.File = ${catalina.base}/logs/catalina**

Comment: I have update the code I used for logger output.
Actually, it works for few months ago. 
But it becomes strange from some day we don't know.

Comment: Logging to console/SYSTEM_OUT is redirected by Tomcat to the catalina.out file.  Remove all the `<appeder=ref ref="Console"/>` lines from the log4j2 configuration file.

Answer (score 2):

It's being redirected to catalina.out because you have console log defined as an appender and these get redirected to catalina.out.

However, we do need console logs for local development but don't want them to show in other environments. You can use ThresholdFilter along with configuration properties to console log only in local and not in other environments with the below sample code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" monitorInterval="300">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="consoleLogLevel">error</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="FileOut" fileName="/dev/pref-api.log"
                     filePattern="/dev/pref-api-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.gz">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%date{yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level [%t] [%logger{36}] %msg%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>

        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%date{yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level [%t] [%logger{36}] %msg%n"/>
            <Filters>
                <ThresholdFilter level="${sys:consoleLogLevel}"  onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
            </Filters>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="warn" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="FileOut"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>

        <Logger name="com.github.api" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="FileOut"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

If you pass a **-DconsoleLogLevel=debug** in local you will see all logs from **com.github.api** being logged to console but in other environments if you don't pass any value it takes default of error and only shows error stack in catalina out.

Answer (score 0):

The below will always point to the default log file Catalina.out.

```
log4j.appender.CATALINA.File = ${catalina.base}/logs/catalina
```

Change the value of this tag to local file

```
log4j.appender.CATALINA.File = C:\outputlog
```

Comment: I mean I define a log output at different place with my own logger module, but the content is still redirected into Catalina.out

Answer (score 0):

If some part of your application is using the log4j-1.2, you can try adding the log4j-1.2-api-2.0.jar to the classpath so that all calls made to the 1.2 api are redirected to the log4j2 implementation. (See the "which jars" section of the log4j2 FAQ page.)
You will no longer need the log4j-1.2 style properties file configuration. Only the log4j2.xml config will be used by log4j2.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I corrected my code with:

```
import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.XMLConfigurationFactory;


public class Logger {

    static {
        System.setProperty(XMLConfigurationFactory.CONFIGURATION_FILE_PROPERTY, "/local/logs/log4j2.xml");
    }

    private static org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger logger = org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(Logger.class
            .getName());

    ...
```

Then it can be generated correct in my log file.
And Tomcat will also put to correct place without application's log content.
 /local/logs/log4j2.xml now looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration status="OFF">
    <appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%msg%n"/>
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="AppLog" fileName="/local/das/logs/das_app.log"
                     filePattern="/local/das/logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/das_app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%msg%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="20 MB"/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>        
    </appenders>
    <loggers>
        <root level="debug">
            <appender-ref ref="AppLog" level="info"/>
        </root>
    </loggers>
</configuration>
```

Thanks for vanOekel